# Referring php variable in html file

Tags: php

Following code is saved as html file:

```
<?php
  $IP = 4;
?>
<textarea name="comments">$IP</textarea>
```

I want to access the value of php variable in html tags.
Example I want the value of IP to be displayed in textarea.

Comment: do you saved your file with `.html` extension??

Comment: I suggest you find a PHP tutorial and start reading it if this is a genuine question ....

Comment: The answer from Jaitsu will allow you to do what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can execute `.html` files as `.php` files by adding a line to your `.htaccess` file..

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`

And obviously use the `<?php echo $variableName; ?>` style syntax

Comment: I am using wampserver and did the same what u said but still no result is displayed(<?php echo $IP; ?>) .

Comment: Worth mentioning you need `AllowOverride FileInfo` in your apache config to do this.

Answer (score 3):

use this:

```
 <textarea name="comments"><?php echo $IP; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: i tried the ablove code but its not working when file is saved .html   this code works file with .php file

Comment: Follow what jogesh_p below said. Save the file with the extension .php so your webserver knows to parse the PHP code

Comment: Otherwise you will just see the verbatim output in your browser, unparsed.

Answer (score 1):

Just put it with PHP

```
<textarea name="comments"><?php echo $IP; ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $IP =4; ?>
<textarea name="comments"><?php echo $IP;?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

it is not possible to access in html, simply save the page in '.php' and if you want to change url, means .html instead of .php then use .htaccess

Comment: can you please explain in detail please

Comment: this isn't quite true, @Sjan checkout my answer

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.ntchosting.com/php/php-in-html.html) is a short tutorial on using PHP in HTML pages. Note that in order to use PHP in an HTML page, you need to save the page with a .php extension.

to answer your question above, you need to do the following:

```
<?php
$IP =4;
?>

<textarea name="comments"><?php echo $IP;?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea name="comments"><?php echo $IP ?></textarea>
```

Extra cool stuff (**for free!!!**):

> http://php.net/manual/en/install.php
>   http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php
>   http://devzone.zend.com/6/php-101-php-for-the-absolute-beginner/
>   *etc, etc...*