# Keep form values after post <?php>

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to keep form values after submit. I found some methods something like that :

However; when I run the html file, first : the code doesn't work, second: php codes can be seen in text areas. What should I do. Thank you for reading.

```html
<form method="post" action="mail.php">
                <label for="Name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['Name'])){echo htmlentities($_POST['Name']); }?>" />
                
                <label for="Subject">Subject:</label>
                <input type="text" name="Subject" id="Subject" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['Subject'])){echo htmlentities($_POST['Subject']); }?>"/>

                <label for="Phone">Phone:</label>
                <input type="text" name="Phone" id="Phone" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['Phone'])){echo htmlentities($_POST['Phone']); }?>"/>
    
                <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['Email'])){echo htmlentities($_POST['Email']); }?>"/>
                
                <label for="Message">Message:</label><br />
                <textarea name="Message" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message">
                    <?php if (isset($_POST['Message'])){echo htmlentities($_POST['Message']); }?>
                </textarea>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="submit-button" />
            </form>
```

Comment: is it saved as a .html file? If so check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207805/referring-php-variable-in-html-file

Comment: right now you are sending the values to mail.php where you can collect them from post array, what do you mean by keep?

Comment: If I remove the text mail.php  nothing changes. I mean <form method="post" action=""> no changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a php page, it's html, change the extension to .php so the browser knows it's got to read some php code.

Comment: The browser doesn't know php.  Changing the file extension would help the server, but only if it was configured to interpret files with that extension.

Answer (score 0):

Your POSTed values will only exist once the form has been submitted, so will initially not exist. If you want 'default' values in your form fields, you need to change the code inside your `value=''` elements to something like:

```
<?php echo (isset($_POST['Name'])) ? htmlentities($_POST['Name']) : 'Default text' ?>
```

Comment: If you're seeing the php code then php isn't being run.  You might need to install or configure php into Apache

Comment: It runs in host (not localhost), even if I change them and press submit button, values turn php codes again.